# Guardar variable de funcion

Tags: jquery

En las siguientes funciones trato de guardar una variable global, pero siempre me da 0.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var error = 0;
    $("#f2").submit(function(event) {

        $('.concepto').each(function(i, elem) {
            var texto = $(elem).val();

            var errores = $.post("procesa-gastosprivado.php", {
                conceptos: texto
            }, function(mensaje) {
                if (mensaje == 'error') {
                    error++;
                    $(elem).css({
                        'border': '1px solid red',
                        'background': '#FF9595'
                    });
                }

            });

        });
        alert(error);
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: Supongo que te refieres al valor de la variable `error`. ¿Has comprobado si se entra en el bloque donde aumentas su valor?

Answer (score 0):

El `alert(error)` lo tienes que poner dentro de la función `success` de post porque la llamada ajax que haces es asíncrona y por lo tanto aun no se ha aumentado tu variable por eso sale `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Este problema es un clásico de JS desde que se empezó a usar Ajax hace como 13 años. ¿O eran 15?

Cuando iteras sobre los elementos con clase `.concepto` ahí dentro llamas a una función asíncrona (`$.post`) que gatilla un request a tu backend php.

El frontend no tiene cómo saber si el backend responde rápido, si le corresponde responder siquiera o si, como en este caso, se pueden gatillar N solicitudes en paralelo, con lo cual competirán entre sí.

En ese escenario javascript no pausa el flujo a la espera de tus funciones asíncronas intermedias. El flujo sigue, y llegas a tu alert antes de que se resuelvan.

## Solución posible

**Paso 1: cambiar el callback a promesa**

La función `$.post` no retorna nada cuando le pasas un callback, de manera que `errores` siempre es undefined.

```
 // Errores es undefined
 var errores = $.post("procesa-gastosprivado.php", {
            conceptos: texto
        }, function(mensaje) {
           ...
        });
```

En cambio, si no le pasas callback retorna una promesa

```
  // Errores es una promesa
  var errores = $.post("procesa-gastosprivado.php", {
            conceptos: texto
        });
```

Las promesas son "thenables" o sea puedes usar la salida de una para meter otra y sigues teniendo una promesa entre manos.

```
 // Errores sigue siendo una promesa
 var errores = $.post("procesa-gastosprivado.php", {
            conceptos: texto
        }).then(function(mensaje) {
           error+=(mensaje == 'error'?:1:0);

           // OJO, la segunda promesa se resuelve cuando retornas algo
           return mensaje;
        });
```

Fíjate que lo segundo es sólo modificar el conteo de errores cuando corresponde y retornar. Desde afuera de la promesa eso se ve como

> oh, que bien, se resolvió la cadena de promesas

Porque el `$.post` ya entregó un `thenable`.

**2 Meter cada promesa en un arreglo**

Ahora que `errores` es una promesa, podemos meter todas esas peticiones en un array

```
 var error=0, requests=[];


 $('.concepto').each(function(i, elem) {

   var conceptos = $(elem).val(),
   // le puse "requestGastos" para entender qué guarda
      requestGastos = $.post('gastos.php',{conceptos}).then(..... );

   // meto la promesa en el array.
   requests.push(requestGastos);
 });
```

**3 Espera que se resuelva el arreglo usando Promise.all**

Ahora requests es un arreglo de promesas. Cada una de ellas al resolverse podrá, si corresponde, incrementar el conteo de errores. Ese conteo tú no lo conoces hasta que todas se resolvieron:

```
 var error=0, requests=[];

 $('.concepto').each(function(i, elem) { ... });

 Promise.all(requests).then(function()=>{
   alert(error);
 });
```

**Ejemplo que no era necesario pero quise dejar**

(me hice una función `$.postFalso` que devuelve una promesa, la cual se resuelve con 'OK' para conceptos aceptables y 'error' si quieres rendir un gasto medio extraño)

```js
const conceptosAceptables = [
  'estampillas', 'transporte', 'alimentos', 'alojamiento'
];
$.postFalso = function(url, {
  conceptos
}) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(!conceptosAceptables.includes(conceptos) ? 'error' : 'OK');
    }, 1200 + Math.random() * 1000);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  const f2 = $('#f2'),
    msg = document.querySelector('#mensaje');

  f2.on('submit', event => {
    let errorCount = 0,
      requestPromiseArray = [];
    event.preventDefault();
    msg.innerText = `enviando...`;

    f2.find('.concepto').each(function(i, elem) {
      elem.className = 'concepto pending';
      let conceptos = elem.value,
        requestPromise = $.postFalso("procesa-gastosprivado.php", {
          conceptos
        }).then(function(mensaje) {
          errorCount += (mensaje == 'error') ? 1 : 0;
          elem.classList.remove('pending');
          elem.classList.add(mensaje);

        });
      requestPromiseArray.push(requestPromise);

    });
    Promise.all(requestPromiseArray).then(() => {
      msg.innerText = `${errorCount} errores`;
    });
    //alert(error);
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
#f2 label {
  width: 92%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-bottom:0.8em;
}

small.comentario {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 5px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
}
small.comentario pre {
display:inline;font-size:1.1em;margin:2%;
}

#f2 label small {
  margin-right: 4%;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}

#f2 button {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 3%;
  
}

input.concepto {
  width: 27%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 2% 0;
  padding: 5px 2px;
}

input.concepto.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: '#FF9595';
}

input.concepto.pending {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background: '#eee';
}

input.concepto.OK {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: '#fff';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="f2">
  <label>Rendición de gastos
  
  
  <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
  <small id="mensaje"></small>
  </label>
  <input class="concepto" value="estampillas">
  <input class="concepto" value="skins para fortnite">
  <input class="concepto" value="transporte">
  <input class="concepto" value="coimas">
  <input class="concepto" value="alimentos">
  <input class="concepto" value="alojamiento">
</form>
<small class="comentario">Todo lo que no sea <pre>alojamiento, estampillas, transporte o alimentos</pre> <b>tira error</b></small>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Es perfecto y muy completo

Comment: Como puedo hacer para que cuando ya no haya errores, envie el formulario

Comment: después del `Promise.all` puedes enviarlo por ajax, algo así como `$.post('ingreso.php', $('#f2').serialize())` ojo que un input de tipo File no es serializable, pero si es puro texto, checkbox, select, radio, dale